# What communication tools do we have on Area51 for discussion / definition?

Tags: discussion, area-51

Apart from commenting on questions that people ask or commenting on a proposal directly, is there any way for site proposal followers to communicate with each other openly?

We don't have a meta...equivalent question / discussion system yet for individual proposals. So.... Discussion **feels** difficult since comment chains would muddy up the proposal page with relevant but potentially subjective discussion / questions to a community.

I just feel like I've been placed into the midst of an *potentially* epic battle with with nothing but a Speedo and a pair of Crocs to defend myself with.  The process doesn't seem natural yet but I am sure eventually it will grow on each community.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a problem with encouraging detailed discussion very early in a process.  Defining a good Q&A site is hard and people will often get caught up in the early process and give [disproportionate weight to trivial issues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkinson%27s_Law_of_Triviality).

Long before the basic framework is established, people would be picking site names and colors,  designing logos, arguing about close reasons, and picking Moderators. And the early followers of a site aren't necessarily the deeply-involved experts who are going to use the site day in, day-out.

So we set up a process that allows increasingly detailed discussion as you go along.

1. **Propose a New Site:** What's your site idea and a brief description of the audience?
2. **Definition:** Set up the basic framework of what kind of questions would typically be asked here?
3. **Commit:** Would anybody use this site?
4. **Beta:** Get the committed experts together to ask the hard questions and confer about the detailed site design and management issues.
5. **Launch:** Is the site working? You're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

> Discussion feels difficult since comment chains would muddy up the proposal page with relevant but potentially subjective discussion / questions to a community.

Well, what more is there to discuss than the description and questions?

In other words, what do you think ought to be discussed that cannot be generated by a well-crafted example question, or by fine tuning the description?

Comment: The answer to my question may simply be that there are no other communication options.  Questions or discussion could be anything from the community, related to the site, related to the target audience, or anything similar in form and function of the Meta.* sites or the FAQ of a site.

Information such as "What kind of questions can I ask here?" would probably save a lot of commenting or voting on "not a good example" questions.  There may not be any really great examples since my question is really spawned based on a feeling.  I'll cope with the system the way it is at the end of the day.

Comment: @Justin - The current method is to define the site primarily by the questions it accepts and rejects.  I can understand the desire to work the other direction - define (or discuss in a more free form manner) the FAQ, the audience, etc. first, or simultaneously.  If you can show how additional discussion would improve the site definition process then I imagine they'd listen a bit better.