# Area 51 proposal's newsletter, meta site and moderation tools

Tags: feature-request, area-51, non-english-speakers

When I create [Persian IT](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2912/persian-information-technology-and-computer) proposal, I wrote a blog post about it and asked people to join and support my proposal, now Persian IT have more than 140 members, most of them with **51 reputation** point.

They are just not active, maybe because they don't know how to use system (don't forget we are talking about non-English users who can't read FAQ or other English guidelines) so I think sending email to new members, you know like *some kind of newsletter*, may solve this.

So in short *is there any way to interact with new members?*, I'm looking for something like meta site (like meta.stackoverflow.com)

Also another question behind this sending email/meta site feature for area 51 is: *Except for those edit/delete permissions which anyone can earn with enough reputation is there any moderation tools?*

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53147/what-communication-tools-do-we-have-on-area51-for-discussion-definition/53208#53208). I think it has very valid points about why there are a "lack" of these tools. You are trying to define on and off topic questions at this stage nothing more, I don't see why you want these other tools? If you want the site in Arabic so users can read the existing FAQ then you should make a post asking for that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Our site is in Persian language. There are three phases for each area51 proposal: define, commit & beta. Defining on-topics/off-topics is just phase 1, also as I said I'm looking for a way to interact with members, newsletter was just an example.