# I'd like the ability to subscribe to discuss.area51 posts by email

Tags: feature-request, area-51, email-notification, tag-filters

Via [the StackExchange™ GlobalTag MegaBlender™](https://stackexchange.com/filters) I can subscribe for email updates to SE sites' questions and Meta questions, but it appears that I can't subscribe to Area 51's "Meta" (Discuss).  I've found it hard to keep up my posting there without notifications, and I'd like to think I was at least somewhat helpful ;).  Can Discuss be added to the subscribable sites?

Comment: Please look at this link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53147/what-communication-tools-do-we-have-on-area51-for-discussion-definition/53208#53208

Comment: @Siva Yeah, that's not relevant.  The discussions are already happening and being closed if inappropriate.  I want to participate in the appropriate ones without needing to refresh the page all the time.

Comment: Is your question concerning [stackexchange.com filters](http://stackexchange.com/filters)?

Comment: @Emmett Yes -- I currently have [this filter](http://stackexchange.com/filters/10073/ae-m-g) subscribing me to emails for all questions on Gaming, Android, and Music plus their metas; I wanted to add Discuss.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using an [rss-to-email service](http://www.google.com/search?q=rss%20to%20email) to consume Area 51 Discussion's [recent questions feed](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/feeds).

Comment: Yep. I've not had good experiences with such services and would prefer to manage everything in one place.